# How to decode file from 'https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle

The command `gem list --remote` makes a http request of 'https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz'.

How to decode this file, while I've extracted it and found some unreadable characters!

Or is there a gem can do it?

All that I do is try to get full gem lists with ruby code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To decode the file use plain old Ruby [Marshal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Marshal.html)

The file is a big gzipped and Marshal'd (binary serialization) Array which contains the gem name, version and platform:

```
$ wget http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
$ irb

> m = Marshal.load(Gem.gunzip(File.read("latest_specs.4.8.gz")))
> m.first #=> ["_", #<Gem::Version "1.2">, "ruby"]
> m[666]  #=> ["activerecord-draft_records", #<Gem::Version "0.5.1">, "ruby"]
> m.last  #=> ["zzzzzz", #<Gem::Version "0.0.3">, "ruby"]
> m.size  #=> 66756
```